# C++ Compiler doesn't write a/A-f/F letter character in output?

Tags: c++, xcode, string, input, compiler-errors

I'm writing a C++ program in Xcode that reports student's name on one column and grades on the other in alphabetical order by reading from an input (project from Accelerated C++ book).

A line of input it reads from looks like this:
`John 90 80 60 70 100` (first is name, next 2 numbers are midterm and final grades, and the last are homework grades contained in a vec).

Once I'm done I hit Ctrl + D (EOF on Mac), Once only - even if 2 reading functions are called, not sure if that's ok - and I get the expected output except for one issue. I've noticed that for some of the input that I give, if the first string in the input (student name) has its first character a letter from a-f (case insensitive) it doesn't write it in my output those letter.

So, for instance if I enter in the console:

`Johnny 70 80 50 60 30
 Fred 95 90 10 10 10
 Joe 40 40 50 60 50 70 70 50`

I get:

`Joe    46
 Johnny 66
 red    59`

If I change the 'F' in Fred with 'G' (aka Gred) I get:

`Gred   59
 Joe    46
 Johnny 66`

I've tried this with multiple input values and it gets buggy if the name starts with a letter from A/a-F/f. I'm thinking this could be something about hexadecimals, parsing, preprocessor magic that doesn't do the trick or just an annoying Xcode bug.

Code below (included just the main and Student_info file where the reading happens):

/// STUDENT_INFO FUNCTION ///

```
struct Student_info
{
  std::string name;
  double midterm, final;
  std::vector<double> homework;
};    
// helper compare for sort() (alphabetically)
    bool compare(const Student_info& x, const Student_info& y)
    {
      return x.name < y.name;
    }

    // read student's name, midterm grade, final grade, and homework grades
    // and store into the Student_info object
    istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
    {
      // read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
      is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;
      // read and store all the student's homework grades
      read_hw(is, s.homework);
      return is;
    }

    // read homework grades from an input stream into a vector<double>
    istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
    {
      if(in)
      {
        hw.clear();
        // read homework grades
        double x;
            while (in >> x) {
          hw.push_back(x);
            }
            cout << hw[0] << ",";
        // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
        in.clear();
      }
      return in;
    }
```

/// MAIN FUNCTION ///

```
int main()
{ vector<Student_info> students;
  Student_info record;
  string::size_type maxlen = 0;   

  // read and store all the student's data.
  while (read(cin, record))
  {
    // find the length of longest name
    maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
    students.push_back(record);
  }

  // alphabetize the student records
  sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);

  // write the names and grades
  for (vector<Student_info>::size_type i = 0;
       i != students.size(); ++i)
  {
    //write the name, padded on teh right to maxlen + 1 characters
    cout << students[i].name
    << string(maxlen + 1 - students[i].name.size(), ' ');

    //compute and write the grade
    try
    {
      double final_grade = grade(students[i]);
      streamsize prec = cout.precision();
      cout << setprecision(3) << final_grade;
      std::cout.precision(prec); // sets
    }
    catch (domain_error e)
    {
      cout << e.what();
    }
    cout << endl;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: I am using Xcode 8.0 on a Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Your reading of the file looks wrong.  You should be reading the entire line into a string, load that into a stingstream, and then break it apart into the separate components.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I don't see any problem in the code that reads the file.

Comment: @PeteBecker If there was nothing wrong with it the OP would not have to call `clear` at the end of the read.  He reads in until the read breaks(starts to read a string into an integer), clears the error and then returns.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I take it back. I do see the problem.